# Laravel 5:7 Determining reasonable setRedrawFrequency for Symfony's Progress Bar to avoid CLI blinking based on a quantity of records to loop

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I work on several artisan commands that do something in a loop over a different quantity of items. Sometimes it's `30` items, sometimes it's `800k` items, sometimes `20k`.

Everything works but sometimes the output blinks. I know why - due to the too frequent refresh.

`$progress = $this->output->createProgressBar($this->countSyncRowsCleaned);`

I came up with determining the refresh rate somehow dynamically based on the volume of records to loop through. So instead of hardcoding:

```
$progress->setRedrawFrequency(50);
```

I do:

```
$progress->setRedrawFrequency(max(1, floor($this->countSyncRowsCleaned / 1000)));
```

Sometimes `50` is great, sometimes it's still to frequent.

What would be a good math formula to set reasonable redraw frequency for a huge spread of integers? Sometimes several records, sometimes over a million.

Thanks for any hints.